# Octave calling function from another m file

Tags: function, call, octave

m file that calls function `nraizes(a)` from another m file.

```
clear functions;
clc;
x = input('Insert value for a? ') ;
% call to nraizes()
w = nraizes(x)
clear functions;
```

nraizes.m file with nraizes() function:

```
printf("\n\n");
printf("nraizes por André Castro - UAB 901396");
printf("\n");
printf("Usar na próxima prompt: nraizes(valor numérico)");
printf("\n");

function n = nraizes(a)

% limpar a memoria de todas as vars e funções
clear functions;

clc;

% intervalo para x
x = 0:.1:25;
% ambas as funções h(x) e g(x)
h = @(x) cos(x);
g = @(x) exp(a*x)-1;
% traçar linha na origem das abcissas
or = x;
or(:) = 0;
% gráfico
plot(x, [h(x);g(x);or]);
axis([0, 25, -1, 1])
title("h(x),g(x)");
grid on;
printf("Fim do Script");
printf("\n");

% limpar a memoria de todas as vars e funções
clear functions;

endfunction
```

It always throws the following error:

```
warning: function 'nraizes' defined within script file '/Users/andrecastro/0_Thawed/1_UAB/1 UCS_INFORMATICA/Computacao Numerica/0 2015-2016_CN/1 Algoritmos_Octave/nraizes.m'
error: invalid use of script /Users/andrecastro/0_Thawed/1_UAB/1 UCS_INFORMATICA/Computacao Numerica/0 2015-2016_CN/1 Algoritmos_Octave/nraizes.m in index expression
error: called from:
error:   /Users/andrecastro/0_Thawed/1_UAB/1 UCS_INFORMATICA/Computacao Numerica/0 2015-2016_CN/1 Algoritmos_Octave/script.m at line 19, column 7
```

I don't undestand why. Both .m files are in same path.

Comment: You have an error on the function `nraizes` (which is a function that you wrote). You say there is a function named nraizes but you did not wrote a function, you wrote a script. To be a function, it needs to start with a function definition.

Comment: I wrote the function nraizes in another .m file. I will edit the post and include the nraizes() now. Edit is done. nraizes.m included.

Comment: Put the function definition as the first line of the file. The first line, not the 7th.

Comment: As beaker said i did it. It worked well and gave the correct graph. But gave an warning -> warning: nraizes: some elements in list of return values are undefined
w = [](0x0)
This warning concerns what?

Comment: Many thanks carandraug :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `nraizes` defined in a file with the same name as the function.  You should not do it because now you have both a script and a function, both named `nraizes` which makes things confusing.

This is what the first warning means:

```
warning: function 'nraizes' defined within script file '[...]/nraizes.m'
```

It is warning that the function is on a script with the same name.

You can do it (it's only a warning) but you shouldn't. If you want to do it, you will need to first source the `nraizes` script and only after that will you have the function available:

```
nraizes; # source nraizes script
w = nraizes (x); # call nraizes function
```

That is why you got an error

```
error: invalid use of script [...]nraizes.m in index expression
```

because you tried to call a function (or index a variable -- remember that the function is not defined yet so Octave does not know) that does not exist.

However, the `printf` statements at the top of `nraizes.m` suggest that you actually want to have it as a function file only.  In that case, you should drop those `printf`'s (replace them with comments and they will be displayed when you run `help nraizes`) so that the first statement is the actual function definition.